# Android Use fonts for dependency package

Tags: android, react-native

I am very new to mobile development. I am trying to use a downloaded font in my react native package. I searched online. The answers are similar, which ask me to create a font folder and put it under src/main/assets/font, but there is no android folder in my package since it is only a dependency package of the main project. I can only run it from the main project. I tried to add font folder under assets folder in main project, but it's not working. I am wondering if I miss any steps? Or is there any way that I can add the font in my own package, but not under android folder? And due to company security, I cannot use npx or npm to link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You will have to make a folder with the name of fonts in assets folder like I did [image: Fonts Folder]

Now, download the fonts

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";

const fetchFont = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    "open-sans": require("./App/assets/Fonts/open-sans.regular.ttf"),
    "open-sans-bold": require("./App/assets/Fonts/open-sans.bold.ttf"),
  });
};


export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFont}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MealsNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Use like below code

```
title: {
    fontFamily: "open-sans-bold",
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```